# Problem with microphone in Unity Android app

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, microphone

I've posted this question on the [Unity forum](https://forum.unity.com/threads/microphone-doesnt-work.999269/) but still didn't get any response so I decided to post it here.

After some changes/updates in our project we have now not working microphone on Android version of the application. On iOS and PC it works without any problem.

Unity: 2020.1
Phone: OnePlus 5, Android 9

In a logcat I see 2 suspicious messages:

```
Debug Unity Failed to install Player data archive: /storage/emulated/0/Android/obb/com.<...>/main.200035.com.<...> .obb/assets/bin/Data/data.unity3d!
```

and error below it says:

```
Error Unity [NetworkLobby.Recorder] Local input source setup and voice stream creation failed. No recording or transmission will be happening. See previous error log messages for more details.
Error Unity #0 0x7c1072776c (libunity.so) GetStacktrace(int) 0x3c
Error Unity #1 0x7c104ec8b4 (libunity.so) DebugStringToFile(DebugStringToFileData const&) 0x1f0
Error Unity #2 0x7c100ef0d0 (libunity.so) DebugLogHandler::Internal_Log(LogType, LogOption, core::basic_string<char, core::StringStorageDefault<char> >, Object*) 0x90
Error Unity #3 0x7c100eeffc (libunity.so) DebugLogHandler_CUSTOM_Internal_Log(LogType, LogOption, ScriptingBackendNativeStringPtrOpaque*, ScriptingBackendNativeObjectPtrOpaque*) 0x128
Error Unity #4 0x7c0cdf2bd0 (libil2cpp.so) ? 0x0
```

I was trying to google this issue but didn't find anything similar.
What can be the reason? Have anybody seen such an error before?

Thanks in advance.